# does linux-macbook kernel work for iMac?

Tags: mac, arch-linux, kernel

I use Arch linux on my iMac16,2 1.0. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mac#Suspend_.26_Power_Off_.2811.2C4.2B.29 as this page says, I can't shutdown or/and suspend my computer. It reboots automaticaly. The solution suggested is to install a different kernel. The linux-macbook kernel. I consider installing it but Im not sure if it is suitable for my device.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to give acceptable answers, we need to know as much as possible from you. Providing more information about your system (What version of Arch and what kernel you are running? Have you installed a custom boot manager like rEFInd or (even worse) rEFIt? What's about GRUB? A forgotten kernel/boot option? Have you already tried to boot via usb/dvd/cd?), results often in more/better answers.

The linked wiki page entry doesn't seem to match your posted "Model Identifier". A quick lookup made clear that those are from `2013` and yours from `2015`. By the way the Arch wiki is of course an amazing and generous *user guide* — but it's also outdated, partially (mostly Apple related). Don't trust it blindly!

...finally, to answer your question: **Yes**, it should!

I'm actually typing this answer on an `iMac12,2`, `2,7GHz @ i5`, `AMD HD 6770M` with multi-boot:

```
SYSTEM           KERNEL
Arch@2017.08.01  Linux@4.12.3
macOS@10.12.6    Darwin@16.7.0
```

---

To fix it:

1. Add more details to your question
2. Read changelogs and release notes!!!
3. Wait…

> [Downgrading](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Downgrading_packages#Downgrading_the_kernel) the kernel to the last known working state, seems to be a reliable solution.